# Instantiate view, then navigate away

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently writing an app where we are launching a walkthrough the first time the user opens the app. At the end of it, we require the user to fill in a few details, and to do so I would like him to press a button to get redirected to the settings page.

The thing is, this page is one level down the navigation controller (from the landing page). As it stands, I can correctly instantiate the landing page, but the redirection to the settings page never happens.

```
let mainView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavCtrl")
self.presentViewController(mainView!, animated: false, completion: nil)
// the above works correctly and sends us to the landing screen 
// (rootView of the navigation controller)

// the following lines never have any effect though
let settingsView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Settings View")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsView!, animated: false)
```

I think it's because I'm trying to call `.pushViewController` before the storyboard had time to instiate either the first or second view.

So I have a few questions:

- Is there a way to, indeed, instantiate a view and then navigate to another one right after it has been instantiated ? (this in order to keep the navigation stack and maintain accurate nav bar behaviour)
- If there isn't, would it be possible to programmatically populate the navigation stack so that I would only need to instantiate the settings view ? This in order to still have the back button in the nav bar that would send to the landing screen ?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: When you do `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsView!, animated: false)` are you sure `self.navigationController?`is not nil? The main view controller is not being presented on a navigation stack, is being presented modally

Comment: In your viewDidLoad of your first view controller, you could add the self.performsegue... to the other view

Comment: you're executing twice. 1ce 'presentViewController' and then 'self.navigationController?.pushViewController'. As you mentioned, the 2 lines below never get executed. All you should do is set up in the navigationController's 'viewDidLoad' you initially push to, to have a function that instantiates to another VC you want it to push to. And to have the back button, embed the on-boarding in a NavigationController.

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers: Unfortunately I can't really do that as the landing page is otherwise shown by default once you launch the app and you have completed the walkthrough. If I did that, it would navigate to the settings page every time you run the app and that's not exactly what I want :p

Comment: @lukesIvi: cf comment above :)

Comment: How are you doing user authentication? If you're using Parse for example, you can determine if the current user is signed in or not and then direct them based on where you want them. @Skwiggl

Comment: @lukesIvi No user authentication... I don't see what that would change anyway though

Comment: You would know whether the user needs to be walked through the app for the first time. If they're already registered then they go directly to the "Home" page, if the user is a new user, then the user is led through the tutorial/on-boarding. @Skwiggs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100233/discussion-between-skwiggs-and-lukesivi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok thanks to @Leonardo for showing me the correct direction !

I solved the issue by doing the following in appDelegate:

```
/*  
*   Override window root view and set it to a newly initialized one
*   view: StoryboardID of view to display
*   navigateTo: if true, set the root view to NavCtrl and then navigate to the desired view
*/
func setWindowViewTo(view: String, navigateTo: Bool) {

    //initalize storyboard & window programmatically
    window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    //if true, navigate from landing page to specified view through navigationController
    if(navigateTo) {

        //instantiate the navigation controller
        let navCtrl = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavCtrl") as! UINavigationController

        //instantiate the landing page & the page we wish to navigate to
        let landingView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main View")
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(view)

        //manually set the navigation stack to landing view + view to navigate to
        navCtrl.setViewControllers([landingView, vc], animated: false)

        //replace the rootViewController to the navigation controller
        window!.rootViewController = navCtrl

        //make it work
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    } else {
        window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(view)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

The important step was to indeed force downcast `as! UINavigationController` when instantiating the NavigationController with the `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier()` method.

Then it's just a case to correctly instantiate the views of the navigation stack you want, and finally calling `navCtrl.setViewControllers([view1, view2], animate: false)`.

Thanks all for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `- setViewControllers:animated:` method to set the navigation stack of a `UINavigationController`

Here's the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:)

But I don't think that's your problem, if I undestood your code correctly, it should be

```
//This is the navigation controller
if let mainView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavCtrl"){

    //Nav being modally presented
    self.presentViewController(mainView, animated: false, completion: nil)

   // Instantiate the settings view
   if let settingsView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Settings View"){
       //Push it to the navigation controller presented
       mainView.pushViewController(settingsView, animated: false)
   }
   else{
      //Can't Instantiate, deal with error
   } 
}
else{
   //Can't Instantiate, deal with error
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws an error saying that mainView doesn't have a member called `pushViewController` (since it was instantiated as ViewController and not NavigationController... ?)

Comment: Oh, I tought it was a UINavigationController because of the Identifier you used `NavCtrl`

Comment: NavCtrl is the storyboard ID of a UINavigationController indeed. Maybe I need to force the downcast ?

Comment: try `if let mainView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavCtrl") as? UINavigationController`